# Filemaker Pro 13 - Filtered Drop-Down field

Tags: filemaker

Our factory rates employees by using 5 ranks:

rank1 - Uncertified
rank2 - Certified
rank3 - Instructor
rank4 - Master Instructor
rank5 - Supervisor

I want to have a layout where 3 fields need to be shown:

1) First field - Drop-down list which shows only employees with rank1

2) Second field - Drop-down list which shows only employees with either rank3 or rank4

3) Third field - Drop-down list which shows only employees with rank5

I don't know how to make each field conditional using the above conditions

I have set up 3 tables:

rank: _pkRankID, RankName

employee: _pkEmpID, EmpFname, EmpLname, _fkRankID

trackingform: _pkFormID, FormDate FormComments, FormRating, _fkEmpID

I am getting very frustrated trying to figure out what fields to use and how to set up a conditional statement.  I either get a ? or a 0 (zero) or nothing in my Drop-down box.
Could someone walk me through step-by-step how to do this please?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to contain your attempts so far and errors / issues you've encountered. This way, other users can assist you without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I put together a sample file that accomplishes this.

It involves:

1. Creating several global fields, corresponding to the appropriate rank ID
2. Create several Table Occurrences on the Relationship Graph, with relationships based on the global fields
3. Create several value lists, which pull from the Table Occurrences you created

You can download the sample file at http://cris.lc/pcuf4

Comment: Hi Cristos Lianides-Chin, Thanks very much for your answer. I have asked this question on a couple of different forums and your answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Cristos, I've run into a little snag. When I tried to duplicate what you did in your sample file, now I get <no values defined>. What am I missing?

Comment: @pademo57 Can you upload your file (or a clone if you need to keep the data private) for me to look at? http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6005/~/saving-and-copying-filemaker-pro-files

Comment: from the file you sent me, it looks like the the zz_g(Student/Instructor/Supervisor) fields are blank. Those fields need to contain the corresponding rank (e.g., if student = rank 1, then zz_gStudent should contain the value "1"). I don't know exactly how your rank system works, but look at this modified version: http://cris.lc/9ghe5

Comment: Thanks Cristos, now the problem is when I click on the student list in my tracking form it only shows one student (the first one). How do I make it so it shows all of the students (rank1)?

Comment: I've also tried adding the supervisors with rank3 and rank4.  In the drop-down it will the first of rank3 and the first of rank4, but not all of the supervisors either with rank3 or rank4.

Comment: It looks OK to me: http://snag.gy/hbRaB.jpg and http://snag.gy/dgnBe.jpg . I also made a modification illustrating how to add supervisors: http://cris.lc/8k0ez